# Как изменить HTML в массиве?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Формирую данные с сервера динамически и храню промежуточные данные задачи в массиве примерно в таком виде.

```
<div class="text">Задача раз</div>
<div class="date">Сегодня</div>
<div class="acept">Готово</div>
```

Код с помощью которого формирую данные

```
function getAndRenderTasks(){
$.getJSON("/tasks/api/v1.0/tasks",  function (data) {

var tasks = [] // Место хранения всех задач

$.each( data, function(key, val) { 
    var taskData = [] // промежуточные данные

    for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 

        $.each(val[i], function(key1, val1){ 
            taskData.push( "<div class='"+key1+"'>"+val1+"</div>") 
        })
    }

    tasks.push( "<div taskId='"+key+"'>"+taskData.join('')+"</div><hr>") 

})

$( "<div/>", { 
    "class": "my-new-list",
    html: tasks.join("")
  }).appendTo( "body")
})
}
```

Проблема в том, что прежде чем отрендерить список задач мне необходимо в некоторые из div задачи, добавить еще данные, типа ссылок, иконок и так далее...
как мне сделать это с помощью js что бы получилось что то типа:

```
<div class="t$event.id">
    <div class="event-text acept">
        <a alt="Редактировать"
          title="Редактировать" href="/editevent/1">
          <i class="edit icon"></i></a>

    </div>
    <div class="event-details">
            <i class="info icon"></i>$event.details
    </div>
    <div class="event-time">
        <i class="wait icon"></i>
       23:33-23:45
         <a class="close-task"
             eventid="$event.id"
             alt="Отметить как выполненное"
             title="Отметить как выполненное"
             href="#">
             <i class="checkmark box icon"></i>
         </a>
         <a class="move-to-next-date"
            eventid="$event.id"
            alt="Перенести на завтра"
            title="Перенести на завтра"
            href="#">
            <i class="external share icon"></i>
         </a>
         <a class="delete-task"
            eventid="$event.id"
            alt="Удалить"
            title="Удалить"
            href="#">
             <i class="remove circle icon"></i>
         </a>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Буду очень благодарна

Comment: Не совсем понятно в какой именно момент и в какие блоки Вам нужно добавить данные

Comment: @Kernel Panic

желательно перед отправкой задачи в общий массив

`tasks.push( "<div taskId='"+key+"'>"+taskData.join('')+"</div><hr>") `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вот так:

```
function getAndRenderTasks() {
  $.getJSON("/tasks/api/v1.0/tasks", function(data) {

    var tasks = [] // Место хранения всех задач

    $.each(data, function(key, val) {
      var taskData = [] // промежуточные данные

      for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {

        $.each(val[i], function(key1, val1) {
          var $elem = $("<div class='" + key1 + "'>" + val1 + "</div>");

          // Изменяете в элементе что нужно

          taskData.push( $elem.get(0).outerHTML );
        })
      }

      var $task = $("<div taskId='" + key + "'>" + taskData.join('') + "</div><hr>");

      // Изменяете в элементе что нужно

      tasks.push( $task.get(0).outerHTML );

    })

    $("<div/>", {
      "class": "my-new-list",
      html: tasks.join("")
    }).appendTo("body")
  })
}
```

Comment: Да! Ваш способ мне подходит как наиболее "родной" ибо jq...
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле вопрос скорее обширный, нежели наоборот. Потому что есть много способов сделать то, что вы хотите. Если я правильно понял чего вы хотите))

**1. Способ**: создавать элементы на лету, добавлять в них необходимые атрибуты и вставлять уже их в родительские элементы

В примере ниже создается ссылка, добавляется к ней заголовок, href и добавляется через [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/createAttribute) (это на чистом js. Для jquery будет скорее всего `append`) в `body`.

```js
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("my title text");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.title = "my title text";
a.href = "http://example.com";

document.body.appendChild(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"></div>
```

А так добавили в див..

```js
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Так можно создавать и добавить узлы друг в друга, сделать это в цикле:  создать одну общую переменную и добавлять в нёё всё и затем эту финальную переменную добавить в шаблон

---

**2. Способ** (из него будет следовать 3 способ): Заводить строковую переменную, в неё складывать все данные, которые есть в цикле (включая атрибуты элементов и прочее) и затем добавить всё это в шаблон:

```js
var content = ''; // это накопительная переменная

for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

  var div = '<div class="key' + i + '">' + getLink(i) + ' divval="' + i + '"</div>';
  content += div;
}

$('#content').html(content);


function getLink(event_id) {
  return '<a class="close-task"' +
             'eventid="' + event_id + '"' +
             'alt="Отметить как выполненное"' +
             'title="Отметить как выполненное"' +
             'href="#">Ссылка № ' + event_id +
             '<i class="checkmark box icon"></i>' +
         '</a>';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"><div>
```

Смысл состоит в том, чтобы разбить код на составные куски (на те, из чего состоит генерируемый блок) и дальше по кусочкам их генерировать и вставлять в один основной блок и далее уже в шаблон.

---

**3. Способ** - использовать шаблонизаторы, например [Handlebars.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) или [mustache.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/) или много других. Смысл их, в принципе, вытекает из способа №2, когда у вас есть готовые шаблоны, которые будут вставляться в определенные блоки и затем вставляться в основной шаблон, при этом не захламляя сам скрипт такими "строковыми накоплениями"

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ! В будущем возможно я воспользуюсь вашим способом.

Comment: @ElectroGirl без проблем. можно уже сейчас начинать потихоньку читать про шаблонизаторы да и про фреймворки, наподобие Angular2 и react js....

Comment: мы занимаемся стартапами и нам на данном этапе не очень выгодно тратить время на таких монсторв как angular. Например первый ангуляр плох тем что ранно или поздно начинает тормозить на стороне клиента, а для нас производительность самое главное. Так же мы хотим сохранить архитектуру гибкой и быстро изменяемой. С экономической точки зрения тоже выгоднее собственный js/jquery код. Находим панацею в микробиблиотеках коих можно найти на все случаи жизни...

Comment: @ElectroGirl тогда React... он шустрый... просто вот такое решение как у вас уже никто не делает и в последствие может вылиться в проблему поддержки и  модификации. Оно как раз **не** является гибким и быстроизменяемым. Наоборот, написав так десяток тысяч строк - будет головная боль)

Comment: да, я понимаю что решение устаревшее и не самое элегантное, но задача запуститься как можно скорее, фреймворки со средними или даже базовыми навыками программирования на js легко не поддаются, а писать на инструменте который мы совсем не понимаем нас раздражает (кстати чем больше "профессиональных" программистов мы знаем, тем меньше они понимают базовый JS и естественно еще меньше понимают фреймворки на которых пишут) после запуска конечно будем смотреть в сторону шаблонизаторов :)

Comment: Мы пришли в js из мира python и привыкли что пользуясь языком мы понимаем его как можно глубже прежде чем начать использовать фреймворки. То что мы делаем сейчас помогает нам понять особенности JS и в будущем поможет совершить безболезненный переход на какой либо фреймворк без потери контроля и понимания языка...

Comment: @ElectroGirl кстати посмотрите еще `vue.js` ... он должен быть быстрым и, на сколько я знаю, очень легок и быстр в освоении.

Comment: интересная штукенция! такое мы любим) спасибо! изучим ;)